# Retrieving and Displaying Additional Data from 'related' tables using Entity Framework Core 6/7

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core

Retrieving and Displaying Additional Data from 'JobTitle' and 'Location' Tables

Table structure [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxhVJ.png)

I can use Include to pull related data (location Ids) from the **CustomerLocations** table.

```
List<Customer> customerList = await _context.Customers
                                                .Include(cl => cl.CustomerLocations)
                                                .ToListAsync();
```

But I also want to show job title and location names so, how can I do it like below

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.customersList.Count; i++)
{
        <td>
            customersList[0].CustomerName
        </td>
        <td>
                customersList[0].JobTitle
                or
                customersList[0].JobTitles[0].JobTitle
        </td>
        <td>
            string.join(",", customersList[0].Locations[0].LocationName)
        </td>
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), also, what is wrong with your code? Syntax error? Post it.

Comment: So `Include` more. Or better: project to a view model that has everything you need in the view and nothing more.